# Cant install wordpress plugins

Tags: wordpress, plugins, vagrant

Today i ran into a problem. I was trying to install a plugin via the Wordpress enviroment and all of a sudden I got the following error: "an error occurred while installing IshYoBoy Multicorp Assets: unable to create directory ishyoboy-multicorp-assets."

I have already tried to give the files in wp-content the 777 permission but that didn't work. Installing the plugins locally works though (downloading the plugin and placing it in the destination folder). It feels like I have tried everything I know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't install Wordpress plugins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35603826/cant-install-wordpress-plugins)

Answer (score 1):

Simply append owner and group arguments to the `synced_folder` config in the Vagrantfile

> ,:owner=> 'www-data', :group=>'www-data'

#### Example

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
        config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
        config.vm.synced_folder "wp-root/", "/var/www",:owner=> 'www-data', :group=>'www-data'
        config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8000
end
```

Comment: Hacking on a Vagrant-based WordPress install, this fixed my plugin uploading efforts, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your web server has permission to write to that folder. Changing the permissions to 0777 may not solve the problem, and it's not a great way to go anyway.

If the folder is currently owned by "root" or some other user, try switching the owner to apache, www, or whatever your server uses for ownership using the chown command.